# how genrerate tree folder with html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following data

```js
const data = {
    name: "Root",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Folder 1",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Folder 1-1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Folder 1-2",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: "Folder 2",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Folder 2-1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Folder 2-2",
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

how do i just use javascript to generate html tags like below. Please help me, thank you all!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tree folder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
</head>
<style>
    .children-list {
        padding-left: 12px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="static-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tree">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                    <span>-</span>
                    <span>Root</span>
                </div>
                <div class="children-list">
                    <div class="children-item">
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                            <span>-</span>
                            <span>Folder 1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="children-list">
                            <div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                                    <span>-</span>
                                    <span>Folder 1 - 1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                                    <span>-</span>
                                    <span>Folder 1 - 2</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="children-item">
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                            <span>-</span>
                            <span>Folder 2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="children-list">
                            <div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                                    <span>-</span>
                                    <span>Folder 2 - 1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold">
                                    <span>-</span>
                                    <span>Folder 2 - 2</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: CSS classes and DOM modification following a JavaScript depth-first iteration algorithm over your JavaScript object. Have you even started to write any JavaScript code? It doesn't look like you included the contents of index.js

Comment: Please do not repeat text to bypass the question limit, it is there to guide you that you probably need to include more information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - a recursive function that walks your data and creates elements and puts them where they belong:

```js
const data = {
  name: "Root",
  children: [
    {
      name: "Folder 1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Folder 1-1",
        },
        {
          name: "Folder 1-2",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Folder 2",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Folder 2-1",
        },
        {
          name: "Folder 2-2",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

function makeEl(tag, props) {
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  Object.assign(el, props);
  return el;
}

function walk(dest, node) {
  const el = makeEl("div", {
    className: "flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold",
  });
  el.appendChild(
    makeEl("span", {
      innerText: "-",
    }),
  );
  el.appendChild(
    makeEl("span", {
      innerText: node.name,
    }),
  );
  dest.appendChild(el);
  if (node.children && node.children.length) {
    const cList = makeEl("div", {
      className: "children-list",
    });
    dest.appendChild(cList);
    for (const child of node.children) {
      const chNode = makeEl("div", {
        className: "children-item",
      });
      cList.appendChild(chNode);
      walk(chNode, child);
    }
  }
}

walk(document.querySelector(".tree"), data);
```

```css
.children-list {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="static-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tree">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `for loop`. Like:

```js
for(i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
  // You can create here a div and give it the name
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "flex items-center gap-x-12 font-bold";
  // .... And continue adding your classes and then append
}
```